# Is there a closed form of $x_2x_3\cdots x_n + x_1x_3\cdots x_n + \dots + x_1x_2\cdots x_{n-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, summation, closed-form

Given real numbers $x_1,\dots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$, does there exist a closed form for the expression
$$A_n := x_2x_3\cdots x_n + x_1x_3\cdots x_n + \dots + x_1x_2\cdots x_{n-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1 \\ i\ne j}^n x_j$$

Obviously the expression can be directly calculated, but is there a form that takes significantly less time to calculate? Maybe with some smart multiplications, divisions and exponentiation.

I found the following relation for the formula:

$$A_n = x_1x_2\cdots x_{n-1} + x_1x_2\cdots x_{n-2}x_n + \dots + x_2x_3\cdots x_n = \\ = x_1x_2\cdots x_{n-1} + x_n(x_1x_2\cdots x_{n-2} + \dots + x_2x_3\cdots x_{n-1}) = \\ = x_1x_2\cdots x_{n-1} + x_nA_{n-1} = \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i + x_nA_{n-1}$$

While it is possible to get the rate of increase of $A_n$ from the above formula, I was already able to get that from the first form; and I wasn't able to manipulate it so that a formula would pop out. I think there should exist a smart way to perhaps factorize a higher degree polynomial into this term and other easy-to-calculate terms.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about $\prod_i x_i \cdot (\sum_i \frac{1}{x_i})$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is this...
$$
A_n = \big(x_1x_2\cdots x_n\big)\;\left(\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\dots+\frac{1}{x_n}\right)
$$
for the case all $x_i \ne 0$.

---

If one of them is zero, say $x_1 = 0$, then $A_n = x_2x_3\cdots x_n$.

If two or more of them are zero, then $A_n = 0$.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Somehow I didn't see that. Oh well! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You can just sum/multiply over the nonzero values.

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea.